# SQL Server - Changes not reflecting everytime until manually doing CHECKPOINT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having an issue in SQL Server procedure.

I have two new stored procedures, with the **PROC_Main** proc performing a bunch of inserts and updates before it calls the **PROC_child** to pull the updated records back out.

```
--Child PROC
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_Child
    @Id int
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee WHERE Id = @Id AND Status=1
    END



--Parent Proc 
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_Main
    @Id int ,@Status varchar(100),@Date datetime
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM dbo.Employee WHERE Id = @Id)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE dbo.Employee 
            SET Status = 3, 
                Date = getdate()
        WHERE Status <> 3 
          AND Id = @Id

        INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (ID,Status,Date)
        VALUES (@ID,@Status,@Date)
    END

    COMMIT
    --CHECKPOINT;
    EXEC dbo.Proc_Child @Id = @Id
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN

    DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(1000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    DECLARE @Severity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    DECLARE @State INT = ERROR_STATE()

    RAISERROR(@Message, @Severity, @State)
END CATCH
END

--Procedure call
EXEC Proc_Main @ID=1,@Status=1,@Date='2019-01-01'
```

I am facing the issue that **Proc_Main** is not returning the records from **PROC_Child** every time.

When I am manually doing checkpoint before **Proc_Child** is called then only it is returning records.

Comment: Without the full DDL of the Procs, and the SQL you're using to call `Proc_Main`, how do you propose we help you here? Unless we can see what you're really doing, and what you're working with, and can replicate the problem, we can't help you. Not telling us this information would be akin to asking a mechanic to fix your car without them looking or touching it, and that the only thing you can tell them is "it isn't working as you expect."

Comment: I have never seen such behavior. SQL Server only uses data in memory, not directly from disk, so `CHECKPOINT` should be irrelevant. Try to create a minimal example that shows the behavior and add the code to your question.

Comment: Code is too long, do you the options on how I can share it ?

Comment: @DBA, it would be best create a **minimal** example rather than the full code. One option is  https://pastebin.com/.

Comment: Edited the post, please have a look now.
@Larnu

Comment: @DanGuzman: please have a look now

Comment: If no row exists in `Employee` with `@Id` then update some of those rows before inserting a row with the specified id? And you begin a transaction inside the `try` but may roll it back in the `catch` _after_ you commit it if there is a problem with the child SP and the parent SP is run within a transaction..

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with checkpoint. Based on your code, if you call main proc with Status != 1, your child proc will not return it. Also, why are you doing `update` if you know that record does not exist? Finally, in the multi-threaded environment this may blow up, you need to lock the id when you checking for the existence.